# JSON object with different generic values

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following generic classes:

```
type SyncReducerAction<TState> = (state: TState, ...args: any[]) => TState;

type AsyncReducerAction<TState, TResult, TRest extends any[]> = {
  promise: (...args: TRest) => Promise<TResult>;
  pending?: (state: TState, ...args: TRest) => TState;
  fullfilled: (state: TState, result: TResult, ...args: TRest) => TState;
  rejected: (state: TState, error: Error, ...args: TRest) => TState;
};
```

I want to define a json object where value can be one of these two. Here is a function that supposedly must accept that object:

```
function get<
  T extends {
    [K in keyof T]: T[keyof T] extends SyncReducerAction<any>
      ? SyncReducerAction<Parameters<T[keyof T]>[0]>
      : T[keyof T] extends AsyncReducerAction<
          infer TState,
          infer TResult,
          infer TRest
        >
      ? AsyncReducerAction<TState, TResult, TRest>
      : never;
  }
>(input: T): ReducersToActions<T> {
  throw new Error("Not implemented");
}
```

It does not work. If I only use one of the types - no problem.

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyiB2BjAShAJgV0RATgQUWAEsB7eAHgBUZgBDYCAPigF4oAKAZzoYC4pqPCABooAOgm0cAc079a8EAG0AugEpWzQfQgBuAFD7QkKHk4IU6LLgLEyVGjtGVUnDABtgz18CgQAHgzwaJxQCsoqzGwA3vpQUGA4JAC2RJwQ-OwSYlKy-C4Q3BoszAAKSanpVK4ewIwG8ZDBRPDSAPyZ3Dr5jgyi2blyAj7FWr16cVAAZh7uU0Tu7uidQj1CojiFtfk1nv2SMkMFRZoC4w1QmwBWEITLHF18Z+t+OEk4-ACibyQ4+zmHHaFYCjZ46AwAXwM+hmSDs8Cg0ggwHIk0ofkCEGCoVi8XiSgA0lAWlAANYQEAkKYCFT5JTkynUygqDFBEKwCyoTDYfCEUgUcKMSZ4qBtDlILnWXnw8ilKS0ZLI3CcKj0ilUmmMJQABkiwrxdIZGuZrKx7LMnKsPNs-NRIvtxPgU1wYL6+odLWdOGGWz27vtnpdx2A-viQodYotEqtNj59m0fR9bj2Sbq-v48AgADdcBcIfpGOwWmAMMB8mp+JKeZxKCQbWQVZRmLioMAABZJADuUEz3e+73YACIAHIkXxEZJgJaK+AMNCDtSQwzGaAAYRIGFnuEo4GgMUmiA3W4+PYwyQARrnJvAFRkoNwcC1pJDoQB6V9QdfJGfEVpQMjQLQiz3hY-7ekB7hhOYSCXDGOChJ2vykpw+iHvA3BhHG6GsIiyLsC277ipY3KxvCkwtIgmw-is3SfkeDA4DukCgo8IiTLQaBoDRTzrpuDFMSIUCHnxGZnpeOAseskzpMAw63txd68ceAmiDeir8A+T6SU4kyEVGxFSvW8DsZx+n8C2jQVGkd7sMJs6iReuCguUKTWWImycCQ7g5rZ9FqMI+pNGgT4KfwSn8buoh2WWp6ORJpysQFIozIs8yLPcXCrHRfHbpFsHJjF8BibgUX0Q54naW6IrXLcc6hdlyl5bg7xfD8fxCWVsUVQlUnxBCSWOpREA-mZUAWQkVnpJkzmTRA7mFF5Pn+YFZohQ8WXhblzE9TpyWzGlSxcettGbYxeUedsPbZk5O1VXiNV3EdmUnfRW2Cc1vyte8lVsX1A0yXJiqjeNiSuVNHBqXemmtDNYNzR5i0QOwkPLSKQVrc9PGvWdkCqfJ97AI+MO3b9eIpXMCyHfVp0qfll1FXFePqQTRPSD9A3xA9dXHVjOU4+9bVfb8TNQ4TWkkwN-X6BCi6GIRAyHPebYbu4aA9mOUCXlAm6kvAJCdvAqj6LQWGcDknHsAAjLLJvwmbFFUViwDsDbptiADt5DpDC4GLb-JmxxaD6Vbrt22IDvDU7weh-77vIoDEDB4O3uy0Yu5QFWyq1kZjZRGNkyEo6ZLqkytICISLIBGyoTsP48iKP8gz8IG3qlKC4T6mKWQHHkUBt6cWYkEQaD6nSBKV5i2JjRNcOZArvct6Y-clH3s3kIKUD5iKXfz0MeDL8wg-D6P5fjy++hAA)

Edit:

Another version where it almost works, but still get the types wrong: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=47&ssc=3&pln=47&pc=15#code/C4TwDgpgBAyiB2BjAShAJgV0RATgQUWAEsB7eAHgBUZgBDYCAPigF4oAKAZzoYC4pqPCABooAOgm0cAc079a8EAG0AugEpWzQfQgBuAFD7QkKHk4IU6LLgLEyVGjtGVUnDABtgz18CgQAHgzwaJxQCsoqzGwA3vpQUGA4JAC2RJwQ-OwSYlKy-C4Q3BoszAAKSanpVK4ewIwG8ZDBRPDSAPyZ3Dr5jgyi2blyAj7FWr16cVAAZh7uU0Tu7uidQj1CojiFtfk1nv2SMkMFRZoC4w1QmwBWEITLHF18Z+t+OEk4-ACibyQ4+zmHHaFYCjZ46AwAXwM+hmSDs8Cg0ggwHIk0ofkCEGCoVi8XiSgA0lAWlAANYQEAkKYCFT8caUcAQKiEyKTCH6RjsFpgDDAfJqfioTDYHCcSgkWykeCcKjMXFQYAACySAHcoPAIGrvu92AAiAByJF8RGSYCWySxDDQurUkMMxmgAGESBh4AwcAyTDFJogXW7cPx4BhkgAjXAXeC0C38bg4FrSSHQh1QZ2u92eiAAJlYUHlvrTuEzgeDYZwEajWZjwDjrUThgA9PWUykLW741AyNBaIsoOYkB2cGEe7Q+4hLlYRaEVb9SZx9L7pb5aIQpaE2EjgOx5Y3YBYhdZ8CuyJMWohNq2+Q9Vs2Cx7GaDHiJJrQ0GgVt0b-675BRPm3cXQ1wB91kmdJgH1Ct3yeVMvwzURI2jXtq3jYCnEmHczD3CcbCPeBn1fTCkH4eVGgqNIMg4P9LyDQCcFBcoUnIsRNk4Eh3AANwgdgqLUYRJkaLE0HjKCKJg9NGV-P1qJLIDTkfPi8WmWZ5kWe4uGvMTcDg8c3E8ADS0ktN9NkkokLQxTrluK0RP4TTvxEV53i+H4-igKjjLouSQPiCEFOJJBz0tQjEGI-iEjI9JMnoiKIGYwo2M49heLCpohNaGzP3EyBUL6MKZkWFSljfK8PzsjMcqfCyIBuO5ivU0qpK0iTHN+Zz3gqvzfNA5EIItYLQsUxJGMijgEIo2MUNOBjKliliEq4sbksGwThJK6DGvs+DIKQmtpA6vLlIWIqMrK5qWO2dUZNcsaq12-aqpq6y1tEjbtNwJyoG1X4tsQibWnuqAuohW0GybAZDl7RUXXcNB1SNKAwygV1SXgEgVXgVR9GXeFOByV92AARhB7HVzEU9ArdJKDBJshcbA3quN1MabWp3DcZfNBgsJ4m2bJgKIAvLmeZxsR6YrLmmYrFn7UZKB90ncVJVp2Uc3lQl-LJCkqRpfIWQxIIQg4fx5EUf5Bn4FoplwKBSlBcIwraDhwbyG3QXYkgiDQMLdYJFR9cEnFwuGiisgOF3LetvBbammLyHCZh2UUx3Q4BF2o7dj2vcUn2VDrIxZfpRkVZYNF-exZ6LfgK3B20PpxDDoZwlUO3FAd3ckHlnD4QcIRGG9gQy8N6IlIKo61MfSvq7BOvzr0-yp+OWozcBefreOEFTnCQG2+CzvD272uHMXvZhmBPvs-VCBOLLQwgA). If I remove `TResult` from `AsyncReducerAction` and set it to `any`, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wIZwLxwIwDcAUETAJ5jBwDKZyCASsACYCuCwUAggjAJYoAPABVqMDDGAA+HHAAU6CcABccUeMkAaOADo9GKAHNUqjMjIBtALoBKHDPVLipClS6o6jFu049+Qxy01JlRWABsYbWEQ+FBJZGZUODNLKxlcAG8iODgwKAgAWz5UFXk9HQNjVWjgdDtsGQAFfKKSkRDwmCliHMoEvmRDAH5VBQ1SwOBtcsqTYNqYeocxJ2y4ADNwsPW+MLCWUcVJapWgqFrO6o6I6f0jOZq6+zVT4B64c4ArYF4D+SOJq9tJx8lBVABRKCg24Ve5XBZLF7jYgAX2cm3o-mQcEMwBggjWk00hLgcWACSSWRyOQsAGk4AM4ABrYBkCDrNRWVSvYSuERAtR0tLvFFEKRjJQncbaAZgVgwao2VRMNgcKCoYQQPwCND86VqGRUuAwAAW+QA7nBkMBLZDQXIAEQAOQg8D4BTA+wK5MkzAdNlRJHIlDgAGEIKxkJIoLyQ5k1khI9HVMhWAUAEacd7IDDe1ToKADQyo5zBqjhpOcWPAABMsiNiajnBrKbTmag2dztfzMELgxLJCQaHgjej9YTEabYLgAAZiTkc3m4A6Zw7iWiSAB6TdhwreqNFuAoKgYPZwDz0I9QZJnjAXhAfbxqpLm6BM1BEIfoZK8HVJXC4jAcijpw2hGtuNCeCqPjcL+KBrAMCDnPuCr-OMqgVlO1aIgC87JMwzCHOhu6VjGrjaKOrYZpwOHSmsJQwE6XZEZKJFYeRVrMeevZFrRSh4RB7hQU+vhwcgawYARQn0KoRq9C0xSlMBk6oam1FQIizSFIpOjnKgEBhAAbsAylJjYeG9OSzBFixxxsdG1YUSpVHtnxWhrDkmx7Dsex-BKdmYQ5HF6ZcVptqBiDOWF6luVMHmPt8vyEWhrGBVWHEgtAEJQtATlJi5NHPLhawonhiHIT60kILJ8V5NpJSjJpCklLptQGcZcjmbVVk2SlAUqellCxRZGxbD5+zJf5pRpWRQ1FXR1IJT8vq2dNA2zVMpI5dOdrQMNJV4QxTHelVNWLXVrRKYupQFrxzxaZdrX6UZJnXV1509YMq0YetjmcUut2DPti1edsuwTd99mDZtIURD2faGNo13w3dDTcfx8VfMtfkAj9pF-ZlO3bUjXGA4YwNwKVRAogGW47jM9zniaEZhMwVqunAmZwJGTLIBA5rINYRAYGJqAVARch4LTItYmL5XAChnXEDLf46EdXaOtd-rK6L4vMFVkvS7r8soQbRuy2reLHcABsOlrtMuCG0HPpq2ooKger8Qa440vSjIsmyHLCFygq0lYpIgPEiTyCAUpewzVQMsg6ycHAjSIik8VDGUdyJ+nzyGRAfDMPF1RChHUeUvFINjeDOPEUSj6hHDyTmDCsyqAMKfXlw+do5M7yLaKi3Z3ICdzL3iKF8Xpeh1YA6O1QPJ8o3wjpGoFdWUkU1x0E4+mOY1iIpMazZ7Q9DO6JWKe5IUhrNUm8UnAcnUqD41+dX1K40iGOLYtsOoS7qnR4nQRqLX3knbu8x0CfwzuYQelNT5wCqpfWC19V7XEiNAro98rTAGMh2IgQA)

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that this is simpler than you've made it.  All of that `infer` and `extends` stuff in the `get` generic doesn't actually do anything.  `TRest` etc. are different for each property and you don't get access to that `TRest` variable anywhere other than right here.

All you need is to say that your generic `T` is a map object where each value is either a sync or async reducer.

```
function get<
  T extends {
    [K in keyof T]: SyncReducerAction<any> | AsyncReducerAction<any, any, any>
  }
>(input: T): ReducersToActions<T> {
  throw new Error("Not implemented");
}
```

When I do that, all of the errors go away except for one line where you have a `never` function argument.

```
fullfilled: (state: CounterType, result: never) => state,
```

needs to be

```
fullfilled: (state: CounterType) => state,
```

Replace that and you should be good to go!

I'm getting proper inference on all of the action creators so your `ReducersToActions<T>` looks good.

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/oN5GdW)

Comment: I tried that, but typing does not work properly then. For example:

```ts
  addAsync: {
    promise: (count: string) => Promise.resolve(count),
    pending: (state: Date, count: number) => state,
    fullfilled: (state: CounterType, result: number, count: number) => state,
    rejected: (state: CounterType, error: Error, count: number) => state,
  }
```

Is wrong because state in `pending` is different than the rest, also I declared one of the count variables as `string` instead of number.

Comment: I added another playground link in my question where it almost works.